# Declaring a pointer to a custom Priority Queue

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

How can I declare a new custom Priority Queue of the type below using a pointer?

```
auto cmp = [](Puzzle* a, Puzzle* b) { 
    return a->getHCost() > b->getHCost();
};


std::priority_queue<Puzzle*, std::vector<Puzzle*>, decltype(cmp)> Q(cmp);
```

Comment: The code seems reasonable. What is not working for you?

Comment: Am I able to declare a pointer and assign the address of Q (the priority_queue) to it? Something like: priority_queue<Puzzle*> *p=&Q; ? I'd like to declare multiple PQs of the same type dynamically...

Comment: How about `vector<decltype(Q)> v;`?

Comment: @LJ__ sure, you can declare a pointer to `Q` eg: `std::priority_queue<Puzzle*, std::vector<Puzzle*>, decltype(cmp)> *p = &Q;` which can be simplified using `decltype(Q) *p = &Q;` or `auto *p = &Q;`, or use an alias instead: `using my_pq = std::priority_queue<Puzzle*, std::vector<Puzzle*>, decltype(cmp)>; my_pq Q(cmp); my_pq *p = &Q;`